# Symfony2 автоматическая мультиформа

Tags: symfony2

У меня есть сущность Объявление. Объявление содержит основные поля: автор' дата создания' цена и т.п.
Объявление должно расширяться в зависимости от типа квартира/машина/одежда и т.п.
Т.е. entity Ad должно быть связано с entity AdFlat/AdCar/AdCloth связью OneToOne в зависимости от того что будет в запросе. Как я могу динамически выставить связь между этими сущностями?

Comment: связь одна? т.е. сущность `Ad` содержит переменную (связь), например `$adType`, где переменная может быть любым типом `AdFlat/AdCar/AdCloth` или у вас три переменные OneToOne? Покажите как пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: Я планировал что сущность Ad имеет связь OneToOne к другой сущности(в зависимости от запроса), которая расширяет первую. Т.е. сущность Ad имеет поля id, author и т.п., а вторая имеет поля, к примеру если это квартира: area, square, liveSquare и т.п. И в зависимости от запроса, мне должна выводиться форма для 2х сущностей и после сабмита отправляться в БД.